# REST services using PHP

Tags: php, rest

I have an application, where client A sends a REST request to Server B with filename as an argument in the URL and the Server B should respond with printing if the file exists in its disk or no.

```
Client A
//Construct the REST call /$url = 'http://localhost/Receiver1.php?file=' . $filename;
//GET request with 'curl'
$ch = curl_init($url);
//Set Curl options
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );

//Make the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

//Get the status codes
$result = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $result;

//Close the curl session
curl_close($ch);

switch($result)
{
    case 200 : 
        return true;
        break;
    case 303 :
        //my code
        break;
}
```

Server B Now at the server side, a Receiver1.php script runs by taking the argument (filename) from the URL and prints if it exists in B or not. In this case, the server is my localhost. How does it get the arguments?

```
$filename = $_GET[file];

//Check if the file exists in the system 
if(file_exists($filename.'.mpeg')) { $result = true; } else { $result = intval(false); }
    echo $result;
```

But in my localhost, what should I run? Should I check with http://localhost/Receiver1.php or what is the way? Please clarify this.

Comment: I hate to be *that* guy, but why not use `Zend_Rest_Client` and `Zend_Rest_Server`?

Comment: @philwinkle: after a quick glance, it seems that `Zend_Rest_Server` is in fact an RPC over HTML, and not REST at all.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Receiver1.php will run when you call it from the client script. If you're trying to capture the output you need to store it somewhere.

Comment: Under what name have you stored your Client A's PHP code?

Comment: @javier You must have glanced *really* quick, because it hanles XML as a feature if you would like it, but it's not required. For more information please visit:  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html  it details how easily you can create RESTful clients and servers without too much work. XMLRPC not required.

Comment: @philwinkle: i didn't mention XML.  but it exposes functions to be invoked via HTTP.  there's no _resource_ concept there.

Comment: Client A's php code is Sender1.php and B's code is Receiver A's code is Receiver1.php

Comment: I really don't know what is this zend framework.

Comment: Client A should get the HTTP status code from B. So, what is this url now? how will the B take argument from the url?

Answer (score 0):

The server can parse the client request string to break up the resource. The trick here is to redirect all URLs to be handled by one PHP script. A typical situation would be to create an .htaccess file to redirect all URLs. I've stolen this .htaccess from Recess Framework as an example.

.htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php [QSA,L]
```

Place that file in your web directory. If you have a properly configured mod_rewrite(please Google for instructions if necessary), all web requests will be forwarded to the bootstrap.php file. Now in your bootstrap.php file, put the following code:

```
echo "Processing: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<br>";
$resources = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
var_dump($resources);
/**
 * $resource now contains the pieces of the client's requested URL.
 * If we know what resource the client wants, we pass the parameter
 * on to that resource's handler.
 */
if( $resources[1] == 'files' ) {
    echo handleFiles($resources[2]);
} else {
    echo "Unknown resource!<br>";
}

function handleFiles($name) {
    if(file_exists($filename.'.mpeg')) {
        $result = true; 
    } else { 
        $result = intval(false); 
    }
    return $result;
}
```

What we are doing here is breaking the URL up into pieces. For example, the client may want to access http://localhost/files/mySoundFile. We break the URL into pieces, "files" and "mySoundFile". We can look at the pieces to determine how to process the request.

This is a very brief example of how to breakup a URL in PHP. I highly recommend using a framework (like http://www.recessframework.com or Zend's REST). Also search for REST php on Google to get some good pointers(http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-php.html). Good luck!.